# Refresh the data of current page in Kaminari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, kaminari

I am using the [Kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari) library for the pagination of some records. These are the files I use.

**views/users/show.html.haml**

```
%table.table.table-striped
%thead
  %tr
    %th Lead ID
    %th Date/Time
    %th Property Address
    %th Connection
    %th Response Time
%tbody#showings
  = render '/showings/list', showings: @showings
#paginator
    = paginate @showings, remote: true, params: {controller: "showings", action: 'index'}
```

**views/showings/_list.html.haml**

```
- showings.each do |showing|
  %tr
    %td= showing.id
    %td= showing.created_at_formated
    %td= showing.address
    %td= showing.connected?
    %td= showing.reply_time_mins_secs
```

**ShowingsController**

```
class ShowingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @showings = Showing.all.page(current_page)
  end
end
```

**views/showings/index.js.erb**

```
$('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@showings, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
$('#showings').html('<%= escape_javascript(render "/showings/list", showings: @showings) %>');
```

So, I need to be able to refresh the data for the current page being displayed. Is it possible to refresh de data using AJAX or JQuery? Only #paginator and #showings sections. Currently, when I press the button of the current page nothing happens.

Comment: did you try add params[:page]? `= paginate @showings, remote: true, params: {controller: "showings", action: 'index', page: params[:page]}`

Comment: Try adding the page parameter, but I do not see how you can solve the problem. I was thinking of using something like $("#paginator .active a").click();